# i want to connect wallet with flutter i use the package connect wallet

Tags: flutter, connect, wallet

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'v.bridge.walletconnect.org' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
E/flutter (17785): #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:721:35)
E/flutter (17785): #1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1914:26)
E/flutter (17785): #2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
E/flutter (17785): #3      RawSecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:299:22)
E/flutter (17785): #4      SecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:77:28)
E/flutter (17785): #5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2483:26)
E/flutter (17785): #6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2926:12)
E/flutter (17785): #7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2931:12)
E/flutter (17785): #8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2786:12)